# How to kill and rerun the main process in qt?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qprocess

I have an app which can run another exe files. Some buttons and connect to the executeable files. When i click the button, start running the another program... this is good, but remains open the main window and  the program still running. I want to achive that the main window stop running (or disapear) when another program is running, and when i exit from the other app, run (or appear and run) the main process.
I tried this:

```
void MainWindow::RunSys(QString sh)
{
    this->close();
    QProcess ps;
    if(ps.execute(sh)<0)
    {
        QMessageBox messageBox;
        messageBox.critical(nullptr,"Error",sh + "Error!");
    }
    this->show();
}

//I call the function this way:
QString sh = settings->value("Run").toString();
connect(pButton, &QToolButton::clicked, [=] { RunSys(sh); });
```

It's working on Linux. Opens the executable program but the main program is till running on Windows. What can I do?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. By _"still running"_, do you mean that the main windows is not hidden (still visible) ?

Comment: yes, and i have a clock on the main window and it still show the current time, and i can click on the buttons (did not freeze).

Comment: To be honest, I can't reproduce your bug, it works with me... How do you call the function ? What is the exact command ? If you can write a minimal reproducible example, perhaps we'll find what's wrong.

Comment: I connect this function to a button this way:
`
 QString *sh = new QString (settings->value("Run").toString());
 connect(pButton, &QToolButton::clicked, [=] { RunSys(*sh); });
`

Comment: You can edit your question to add these additional information. Alos I don't understand why you use a `QString*` instead of a `QString`.

Comment: Its also good with QString but the issue is same. I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce the bug, we'll need you to provide a complete, minimal and reproducible example that illustrates the bug.

If it can help you, I've written the following sample code based on yours:

*Header*

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    protected:
        QPushButton * pb;

    public:
        MainWindow();

    void runShellCmd(const QString & cmd);
};
```

*Implementation*

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    // Build the main window
    resize(600, 400);
    pb = new QPushButton("run cmd", this);
    this->setCentralWidget(pb);

    // Create the command
    QString cmd("ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6");

    // Connect the signal
    connect(pb, &QPushButton::clicked, [=](){runShellCmd(cmd);});
}

void MainWindow::runShellCmd(const QString & cmd)
{
    QProcess ps;

    this->close();

    int exit_code = ps.execute(cmd);

    switch(exit_code)
    {
        // Do what you want with exit code
        default:;
    }

    this->show();
}
```

*Main function*

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

And it worked fine.

---

**EDIT:**

I have understood what's wrong. Your example with *calc.exe* has whispered me the issue :)

Actually, `QProcess::execute()` blocks until the command call returns. In this case, it returns right after the launch, not when the windows is closed. So you got the expected behaviour.

I'm afraid that it will be way much harder to do it this way. Because *calc.exe* being an external program, except if you can read kind of closing signal from an external program, you would not be able to detect when it is closed.

Comment: If i use your full code its working. But in my program is the same issue :( The main window is disapear when i click a button, but the other program and the main window appear the same time. The main window is not blocked and running (run the clock and i can click the buttons as often as I want) ( for example one button is execute calc,  i click it the main window disapear and a few moments later appear the calculator and the main window ).

Comment: So i feel that the program dont stop before " this->show(); " it doesent wait for the other program just execute the this->show() command.

Comment: Oh if i change your cmd to "calc" the isse is will be the same :(

Comment: ahh :( its make me crazy :(( any other idea? :((

Comment: @Kaguro Actually, this is normal, because the `QProcess::execute()` waits until the run command returns. When you run _calc.exe_ it returns after the launch, not after the closing. So you get what's expected. You can do the test, if you run _calc.exe_ in the _cmd_ console, you'll see that you'll get the console return right after the launch and therefore you would be able to use the console even if _calc.exe_ is not closed.

Comment: Yeah thats true. So i cant make this to what i want? Because on Linux its working :(

Comment: @Kaguro It works on Linux because by default, Linux programs hold the console until process end unless you explicitly detach them by appending `&` in the command call. It seems that on Windows, the behaviour is the same as if you appended `&` in the command line in Linux. I'll try to find a way to change this.

Comment: @Kaguro To do the same on Windows, I don't see other solution that using the [Windows API and run `CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-processes) instead of the Qt `QProcess`. You will have much more control.

Comment: ty for your help :) I will try it some way.